# SVG container blocks content when using D3 Chart?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I am using this D3 Plot [click here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7608400) when I use the exact code they give in the demo, I get a SVG container that is 960px by 500px taking up whitespace above the plot. How do get the SVG to not take up space while still showing the D3 plot? I would paste the code up here but its too long, but the plot isn't as complicated as other D3's so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show a fiddle with the effect?

Comment: When I put it in a fiddle it doesn't create the svg container? It only creates this whitespace container effect when I incorporate this feature in a browser or in my mean stack application. I'm struggling to understand this concept because its the same exact code..